# How to change scaling

Tags: display, airplay

I have a 2020 M1 MacBook Air.

When I connect my external 1080p/32" monitor in mirroring mode, via AirPlay, my scaling changes.  I like this scaling very much, it is much more usable for me than the default scaling options in System Preferences.

How can I force macOS to always use this scaling without connecting to a second screen?

I have already tried scaling options in System Preferences → Displays and set it to "More Space".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if you want a higher ("more space") or lower resolution ("larger fonts")? AFAIK, it's not possible to go beyond the native resolution of the display.

To get the option for *lower* resolutions, some models require a change to lower-than-native refresh rate.

This is the case, for example, for my M1 MacBook Air on the Pro Display XDR: it only shows the `scaled` option when the `Refresh Rate` is changed from the native 60Hz to 59.94Hz or lower.

Comment: sorry i was not specific enough. i want more space, i want things to get smaller so more thing would fit in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your screens are not only different dimensions, but different ratios. The MBA, with 2560 x 1600 pixels  (a ratio of 1.6) changes its display so that it can map onto your external display, of 1920 x 1080 (a ratio of 1.77).

Furthermore, your MBA screen has 227 pixels per inch; the external has 69 pixels per inch. That's bigger pixels than the first ever Mac in 1984!!

Yes, your Mac can 'fake' any screen dimensions and ratio in software for mirroring, but it's very hard work for the GPU.

You may get more options in **System Settings** in **Display > Advanced**, and clicking "Show resolutions as list"; and then there should also be a switch to show "all" resolutions.

Otherwise, there are third-party utilities that provide additional dimensions.